# what's bodyParser() and CookieParser

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

wht's the role of 
`app.use(bodyParser.json());`
`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());`

and what's the difference between bodyParser() and CookieParser()

Comment: One parses the body of the request, other - cookies?

Comment: that's actually four questions in one - i recommend you read the api docs and do some googling since each one of those answers will be quite long

Answer (score 3):

[body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) is a body parsing middleware, which populates the `req.body` with (for example) the value of the parametres of a `POST`.

[cookie-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser) parses cookies and populates req.cookies with objects bidden to cookie names.

Answer (score 0):

**[bodyParser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser).json()** - a middleware used for going over POST request data, parse it into json on put it on req.body.

**[cookieParser()](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser)** - a middleware that parse cookie header and populate req.cookies